# Headhunter on behalf employer requested "Reference Letter"

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

A few days ago a headhunter called me and offered me a vacancy that might be suited for someone with my skills and I accepted the offer. After that she emailed me a formal interview letter with date & time location.
What confused me is that she requested me to bring a "Reference Letter from my direct report" from my previous companies and current company, which I absolutely can't get because it's not ethical to discuss reference for resigning and I can not guarantee I will get the job.
How do I respond to headhunter/the employer?

Comment: > from my previous to current company **Why can't you give them a reference from a prior employer?** That sentence seems to let you get the reference from a past job. Is that not an option?

Comment: I have not contacted my first manager in almost 5 years, i did not know how to start because i still feel guilty leaving even after he is giving me another solution and i said no.

Comment: My previous manager is an Accounting manager and he is not fully support/help me to push the user doing testing on their requested application, it was hard time because i did my job and the user did not want to use my application and i have no one to ask help. so i left. oh yeah the user like  "so far i am doing good with my job which is years more than you in this company, why should i use your apps and change my works?"

Comment: and for the current company i absolutely could not ask reference letter because my Manager is an HR Manager and it is really sensitive at time like this to resign, because our company has cut off more than 100 contracts employee(not permanent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing *unethical* about asking your current manager for a reference, but of course you have the reasons not to do this, because it will disclose your intention to leave.

If you put job security above new opportunities, you can come without the reference letter and say you can ask your current manager to write one once they make you an offer.

Comment: thank you, this might be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Some companies just insist on hearing some feedback about an potential employee's past performance/behaviour. It's not totally unreasonable I think. However you also have good reasons not to let your current manager know you are looking elsewhere.

But sure you can give them something ? There must be 2 or 3 people you work with now (members of your team/clients/colleagues from other departments) who have something good to say about you and who can keep a secret. If you are still on good terms with a former manager you can also include him/her.

Ask those people if they are willing to provide you a reference and present these to the headhunter/company and politely say that they will have to do with these.

Comment: i will try to explain to them. usually in my country we have 3 phase interview, 2 from departments/users and one from HR. I will bring next time if i still had a chance.